# ASP.NET Web API 2 local MySQL code first

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, mysql-workbench

I have done simple Web API project using SQL server database with code first approach, [see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/821439/Getting-started-with-ASP-Net-Web-API-using-CodeF). But I am not getting any helpful complete tutorial which explains how to create Web API using code first approach with MySQL as database. Could you please give me some sample example.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much difference since both are relational databases. You need to install the corresponding nuget (`Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity`), update connection string and you should be good to go

Here is detailed example - http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider